# How do I get this old phone to ring?

Tags: power-supply, transformer, switches

I’m working on a project where the ultimate goal is to have a button or switch activate a phone ringer. I found some old phone motors on eBay, but I have no idea what I would need to make them work. Is there a simple way to achieve this?

What I’ve come up with is that I need a transformer, button, and power source.

This is the type of thing I’m looking at:

[image: This is the type of thing I’m looking at]

Comment: Likely something in the area of a chopped 100 VDC. If you can find one of these old [vibrators](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g84KJ.png) that we used to use in radios in our old automobiles you'd be golden. They were designed from the ground up for continuous use. So they last a while, too. Otherwise, you can just wire up a relay for this.

Comment: 25 Hz AC, IIRC about 50 V

Comment: I remember 90V but also remember that they should work across a range of voltages, so start lower and work your way up.  The key is that you do not simply apply a flat DC voltage you need some frequency to it.

Comment: If the called party's line is available, the terminating exchange applies an intermittent alternating current (AC) ringing signal of 40 to 90 volts to alert the called party of the incoming call.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telephone_call  start with that, see what happens.

Comment: Getting this bell to ring is not a beginner's project. In the early days of electronics, the complexity was centrally located whenever possible (wanted to keep phone as simple as possible). You need about 60-90 VAC at about 20 Hz. I would investigate using a push-pull inverter, but finding an appropriate transformer could be difficult, 25 Hz is not a typical frequency. https://www.deepakkumaryadav.in/2021/06/Push%20Pull%20Inverter.html

Comment: All telephone systems I worked with used 90VAC at 20Hz to ring a phone.

Comment: In USA, 90V and ~20 Hz for the *basic* ringer, but on a "party line", i.e., shared circuit, ringers were used with different resonant frequencies, so only one phone would ring (loudly - others might vibrate a bit)... although *anyone* on the line could pick up a phone and listen in to the conversation.

Comment: Get yourself an audio amplifier, generate a 25 Hz tone, hook it up to your telephone ringer and turn up the amplifier volume until you have decent level of mechanical ringing.

Answer (score 1):

These things want about 48 VAC at 17 or 20 Hz (or similar frequency)

You can re-wire the coils in parallel for 24 V operation and drive them with a bipolar, or BTL, square wave instead of AC.

They'll probably work acceptably at even lower voltages, possibly as low as 12 V.